# Get my Windows box and a Linux Oracle VM instance to talk to each other and the web

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Windows 7 and the latest version of Virtualbox. I have an Ubuntu VM instance running and I would like the VM & my native OS to talk to each other & the web.

Following advice I have read on different forums I have set up bridged networking with all the defaults and using my network card [screenshot of my VM network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmp9z.png)

However my host still can't talk with my VM. My VM has an IP of the form 197.237.xx.yy while my host ip for my main network card is something other than 197.237.xx.yy
I have tried several permutations on the bridged adapter settings e.g setting full promiscuous mode, partial etc but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the OS in the VM setup to use DHCP? Can the VM reach the Internet currently?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It reaches the Internet when I use NAT, never when I use anything else. The VM is set to automatically use DHCP.

Comment: Have you tried renewing the IP address within the VM? I had your problem until I did this (though I was using Ubuntu as the host).

Comment: You should use private addresses, not public, routable addresses, for all of your LAN. When you do, bridge networking will work.